# How to reverse a regular expression in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I was trying to reverse a motif which is like a regular expression.
An example of my motif : `TA[TC]AA`
When I use the function (reverse) it reverses the `[` into a `]`, so I obtained something like : `AA]CT[AT` and I want something like `AA[CT]AT`.

What can I do for it?

Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the square brackets are the only problem, use transliteration to switch them:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Syntax::Construct qw{ /r };

use Test::More tests => 1;

my $motif    = 'TA[TC]AA';
my $reversed = 'AA[CT]AT';

is reverse($motif =~ tr/[]/][/r), $reversed;
```

Or, in pre-5.14 where `/r` isn't available:

```
my $r = reverse $motif;
$r =~ tr/[]/][/;
```

Comment: Nice! It is working, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Could you please explain the use of Syntax::Construct here? I hadn't seen it before. It looks really useful.

Comment: On 5.14+, it does nothing, on older Perls, you'll get a meaningful error instead of a random parser failure for the `/r` modifier. See [Syntax::Construct](http://p3rl.org/Syntax::Construct).

Comment: @choroba `$r =~ tr/[]/][/;` you made it simple :)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot reverse all Perl regular expressions. But in this simple case where you only have literal characters or simple character classes, you could use an approach where you disassemble the regex atom by atom, then reverse the list of atoms. Here, an atom would be any regex thingy that matches independently, e.g. a literal character or a charclass.

```
sub reverse_pattern {
  my ($pattern) = @_;
  my @atoms;
  while (length $pattern) {
    # parse a literal (here, we just match letters)
    if ($pattern =~ s/^(\w)//) {
      push @atoms, $1;
    }
    # parse a charclass: \[ ... \]
    # the inside of a charclass is anything except "]" or "\": [^\]\\]+
    elsif ($pattern =~ s/^(\[[^\]\\]+\])//) {
      push @atoms, $1;
    }
    else {
      die "Unsupported pattern syntax: $pattern";
    }
  }
  return join '' => reverse @atoms;
}

use Test::More;
is reverse_pattern('TA[TC]AA'), 'AA[TC]AT';
done_testing;
```

Comment: at the line "elsif" can you explain me this at the substitution ?
(\[[^\]\\]+\])

Comment: @Leelouh see my edit. The `[^\]\\]` is the character class matching anything except closing brackets `]` or backslashes `\ `. That is an approximation for the syntax of Perl regex charclasses if I don't want to handle escapes. A better regex that supports escaped characters within the charclass would be `s/^(\[(?:[^\[\]\\]+|\\.)++\])//s`.

Comment: Ok thank you! It is not clear for me yet but I will try to understand it, ah ah.

Comment: To be entirely honest, the regex wasn't entirely clear to me either. That little test case caught multiple problems with that line before I posted the answer.